# How to disable switch camera feature (front/rear) when opened from my app programmatically

Tags: android

In my app I want to open device's camera facing either front or back.

Also I want to disable the switch camera option after the camera is opened.

So if I open front camera I should not have the option to switch modes.

Below is my code so far.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);// for front
        startActivity(intent);
```

**How to disable switch camera feature (front/rear) when opened from my app programmatically?**